# HOw to manage newly added methods into WCF service

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I have created wcf service and added its refernece into web application project.

Have added as below way: 1. generated proxy and config file using - svcutil command and added proxy file into web application project and merged configuraiton file.

Now, I have added some new methodsinto the wcf service , do i have to use - SVCUTIL command on each time or it should work automatically.... for now, i need to generate proxy file each time.. please suggest some best way.

NOTE: service instance available into ASP.NET web applicaiton (client) but unable to get when use client as - MVC applicatoion. please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response.

I found the answer, when add service reference (for MVC application) >>> click at 'Advance' button >>> uncheck the "reuse object....." option and then add it.

Then, service client reference is available and it works.

Just for KS, sharing you another design issue due to `Add Service Reference` option at below link:
[What should keep into this design approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323112/what-should-keep-into-this-design-approach/24323285?noredirect=1#comment37632155_24323285)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In the Web Application, open the Service References folder.
Right click on the Service you want to update.
Select Update.

Comment: did that but, unable to get updated service reference, even method has operatinalcontract atribute as well. When i generate proxy again using svcutil.exe then it works. please suggest what to do.

Comment: This is supposed to work, please make sure that in the App/Web.Config the endpoint points to the url of the updated running WCF host

Comment: My client applicaiton as MVC 4 application. if i add refereince into WEB applicaton or console then it works. but not into MVC. please guide.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help, there is no difference in an MVC app, you should have a service reference folder where you can add and update services according to the web.config, Good Luck