# What should keep into this design approach

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, dto

My Project solution is as below:

1. MVC Project  (Containing reference of both projects listed below)
2. WCF Service containing business methods  (Containg reference of below listed project)
3. Common Project for DTO or BusinessOBject

IN MVC - Calling the WCF service method is as follow -     `IList<Employee> RetriveData()`
it is called from MVC -   ServiceClient.RetrieveData() , now problem is return object `Employee` point to `ServiceHost.Employee` object instead of - `Common.DTO.Employee` object (Library project) so, it gives type casting error.

Can any one suggest me what is the solution over here or i should remove "Common.DTO" project refernece from MVC and only use `Servicehost.Employee` object.

Please guide me on this design, what should use.

NOTE: all objects are DATACONTRACT (serilizable).
In MVC applicaiton, after retrieing DTO object, i do convert them into Viewmodel (It also internally refer any collection object like `IList<ServiceHost.LookupItem>` . Does it ok to use all generated serilized object directly OR , do i have to convert/cast each return object into `common.DTO.` object and then convert into ViewModel ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** use *Visual Studio's* **Add Service Reference**.  Doing so will result in *multiple types* being defined in the solution and *client-proxies* that over time will become *out of sync*.

It is much better to define a common contracts assembly that your whole solution uses.

Please see *[WCF the Manual Way…the Right Way](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39837)* specifically page 3

You should try to follow patterns such as canonical data model whenever possible.  This means the same type for POCO ORM; WCF; and as aggregates in your view model.  Data conversion is expensive; leads to increased maintenance and possible fidelity loss. http://www.soapatterns.org/  http://www.eaipatterns.com/

Comment: I have gone through that approach and generated proxy class using svcutil and added it into client MVC application (removed sevice reference). Now, there is no reference of - `Common.DTO` project though return object is type of `Common.DTO` type. Some further questions -1. Do i have to generate proxy each time when service is updated or any way to directly update service 2) Do i have to add "Common.DTO" at client project or its fine to refer from proxy class's reference 3) What is the difference to refer proxy class  `COMMON.DTO` and `ServiceHost.DTO` as both are serialized objects. Thank You

Comment: Did you even read that article?  **svcutil** is just as bad as **Add Service Reference**. Your **Common.DTO** should be your contracts lib so why did you remove it? 1) yes and that's the problem with generated proxies. 2) You should refer to **Common.DTO**  3) Read article **again**

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what level of abstraction you want.

If `ServiceHost.Employee` is your domain model and MVC is your presentation layer then it would make sense to use a DTO to bridge the gap here. Given that's the approach you seem to want to use then the solution would be to have `ServiceClient.RetrieveData` return `IList<Common.DTO.Employee>` instead of `IList<ServiceHost.Employee>`.

Comment: Please find updated questio with more details. I want to know , will it be ok to use ServiceHost.Employee or it is wrong. And i have to use Common.DTO.Employee in MVC... is any impact or cost?

Comment: @user3711357 Yes there is an impact and cost. See my answer

Comment: Ok, But, service client is return `IList<ServiceHost.Employee>` only. Even though, WCF service and MVC both the applications have same project reference that is - `Common.DTO` . How should i add service reference of WCF service into MVC project so, i do not need to write casting logic from `ServiceHost.Employee` to `Common.DTO.Employee` and direclty return object as `IList<Common.DTO.Employee>`. Thank You

Comment: @user3711357 It's explained in that article.  Basically you add a reference to a new client proxies assembly you page.  Refer to page 5 of that article I mentioned